# Can I have a dot and a double subscript at a single letter?

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

I cannot get a double subscript to a letter that has a dot on it.

I only get what is in the first line of the picture, but what I want is the upper left with the dot only on the `v`. Note that the second `vkd` is not right.
[image]

I use this code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

% no errors here\dots
${v_k}_d$
${{\dot{v}}_{k_d}$
${\dot{v_k}_d}$

% this does not work as I thought it should
${{{\dot{v}}_k}}_d$
${{\dot v}_k}_d$
${\dot v_k}_d$

\end{document}
```

Any ideas??

**Follow up**

As the comments have shown, there is some doubt that these double subscripts are really necessary. They may be hardly visible, but they flatter the eyes - as I think - and make reading more comfortable. The picture below is what I write in original size.

This is also what the `\usepackage{microtype}` does. And, kerning doesn't bother you unless you know about it... Cf. this [xkzd](http://xkcd.com/1015/) cartoon.

[image]

Comment: Is this `\dot{v}_{kd}` what you want?

Comment: Sorry, no. I want the subscript of the subscripted letter.

Comment: I guess this notation is supposed to mean that `$v$` is indexed by `$k$` and by `$d$`... Isn't the notation `$v_{k,d}$` more usual (and convenient) for this purpose? To be honest, I don't understand why `${v_k}_d$` (top left) doesn't give the "double subscript" error as well.

Comment: The only thing that makes some kind of sense is `${{\dot{v}}_{k_d}$` (top middle).

Comment: @Jan, sorry. It's not clear to me what you want.

Comment: @Martin Maybe, but it's more inline with what I describe, if I have the doubled subscript.

Comment: I will insert some lines in the picture, so that the differences are better visible

Comment: I don't think that a reader can really notice the difference between `${v_k}_d$` and `$v_{kd}$`.

Comment: Besides the technical question, I wonder what does your notation mean (let me forget about the `\dot`, even though it is exactly the difficulty). What I understand is that `v` is a list of list (or replace list by sequence, tuple, or whatever), then `v_k` is the list of index `k`, and `{v_k}_d` is the element of index `d` in `v_k`. If I am not wrong, then I think it would be much clearer to denote it by `(v_k)_d`, and thus `(\dot v_k)_d` for the dotted version. Of course, another option is to opt for double scripts such as `\dot v_{k,d}` or `\dot v_k^d` if exponents are possible.

Comment: Ok. $v$ is a function. $v_k$ refers to a discretization. $v_d$ is a certain part (the divergence free part). There is a difference in first discretizing and then taking the div-free part, rather than discretizing the div-free part. So $(v_k)_d$ would be OK, if I wanted to spend parentheses for this issue. I thought $v_{k,d}$ does not represent the noncommutativity well, as does $v_k^d$...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find the notation

```
${v_{k}}_d$
```

unclear; readers won't be able to distinguish it from

```
$v_{kd}$
```

However, if you really insist on doing it that way, you just have to add a pair of braces; I add what I'd do, instead.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

${v_{k}}_{d}$

${{}\dot{v}_{k}}_{d}$

Better:

$(v_{k})_{d}$

$(\dot{v}_{k})_{d}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

It's a problem with math accent that sometimes shows up; in an expression such as `${\dot{v}_k}$` the outer braces are stripped off by rule, because they contain a single *Acc* atom; therefore the intuitive

```
${\dot{v}_k}_d$
```

gives a `Double subscript` error. Adding an empty subformula avoids the problem.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Also for the explanation what goes wrong here ...

Answer (score 1):

Of course, this is in `\textstyle` (going into `\scriptstyle`.  If you need to use it in `\scriptstyle` (going into `\scriptscriptstyle`), let me know.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\makebox{${\dot v}_k$}_d$
\end{document}
```

[image]